# How to implement “stencil” pattern using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of points with x,y,z coordinates and “values” say ints. I want to select a new enumerable such that for each value will be equal to  ‘value + value[up] +... + value[down]’ so a stencil that uses all surrounding values only if they exist. How to do such stencil pattern with linq?

Comment: It is not really clear what `value`, `value[up]`, etc. are. Can you perhaps give some sample input, and sample output?

Comment: Write some code, then with the bit you can't do, ask for help.  At the moment, you have vaguely described a problem, but it's very unclear.

Comment: You want to group the items by a range.  So I would use the math function Math.Round() to group the items so you get a range of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, create a method to say if two values are neigbours:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
    public int myValue;

    public static bool IsNeighbour(Class1 c1, Class1 c2)
    {
        bool ret = ((Math.Abs(c1.x - c2.x) == 1) && c1.y == c2.y && c1.z == c2.z) ||
            ((Math.Abs(c1.y - c2.y) == 1) && c1.x == c2.x && c1.z == c2.z) ||
            ((Math.Abs(c1.z - c2.z) == 1) && c1.y == c2.y && c1.x == c2.x);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then, you could call:

```
//lc is a List<Class1>;
var result = lc.Select(currItem => 
    lc.Where(anItem => 
        Class1.IsNeighbour(currItem, anItem)).Sum(item => item.myValue) + currItem.myValue);
```

For each item it'll select its neighbours, sum them up and add the current item value.

If your logic also consider diagonal elements or other thing, all you have to do is change `IsNeighbour` accordingly